# Add a class to one element in ngFor loop based on router.url match Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

This is a progress timeline where the width of the class="bar" needs to change if the user is on the current chapter. I need to add an active class to the bar class if the id matches the current router.url.

Below is the markup.

```html
<div class="progress-container" >
    <div [id]="chapter.slug" class="bar" [class.active]="active" [routerLink]="'/'+ chapter.slug" *ngFor="let chapter of chapters; let i = index;">
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <p>{{i + 1}}</p>

        <div class="question-dots">
            <a href="" [routerLink]="'/'+chapter.slug+'/'+question.slug" *ngFor="let question of questions"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my component.ts file I was setting active to true using an if statement like below:

```js
    for(let i = 0; i < this.chapters.length; ++i)
      {

        console.log(this.router.url.indexOf(this.chapters[i].slug) > -1);
        if(this.router.url.indexOf(this.chapters[i].slug) > -1){
            this.active = true;
        }

      }
```

However that adds the active class to all the elements inside the for loop. How would I add the class to just the 1 element that matches the router url?

Answer (score 1):

You can set class with `[ngClass]="getBarClass(i)"` where `getBarClass` is a function in the component that takes the index and returns a list of classes, either `['bar']` or `['bar', 'bar-active']` based on the index. And then you can apply whatever you need additionally to the `bar-active` class.

Check [NgClass doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Answer (score 0):

ngClass is the correct way to set the class dynamically in the template. However, it is discouraged to use methods in templates as these are reevaluated on every loop every time the component is updated.

A more efficient way would be to store the calculated value on your chapters object if you can.

```js
    for(let i = 0; i < this.chapters.length; ++i) {
      if(this.router.url.indexOf(this.chapters[i].slug) > -1){
        this.chapters[i].active = true;
      }
    }
```

Then in your template you can use ngClass to query this property of a chapter

```html
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div 
        [id]="chapter.slug" 
        class="bar" 
        [ngClass]="{'active': chapter.active}" 
        [routerLink]="'/'+ chapter.slug" 
        *ngFor="let chapter of chapters; let i = index;"
      >
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <p>{{i + 1}}</p>

        <div class="question-dots">
          <a href="" [routerLink]="'/'+chapter.slug+'/'+question.slug" *ngFor="let question of questions"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

NgClass can be used in many ways, but here I am testing if cpater.active is true and if so I add the active class to that dive.

Further reading: [NgClass Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)